# Efficient algorithm for calculating determinants

Tags: matrices, algorithms, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

Are there efficient algorithms for calculating determinants of matrices?

Comment: LU decomposition.

Comment: @copper.hat Take into account that LU is not the algorithm, but the output, which could be obtained by [many algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Algorithms). Algorithm would be [Gauss elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Comment: @cactus: I am aware of that, thank you; the original purpose was a brief suggestion of direction rather than a complete answer.

Comment: Gaussian elimination is the LU decomp.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some context to your question (e.g. "because I want my computer to go fast!"). It is an interesting question, but won't get reopened unless you provide some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a slight variation of Gauss elimination on the determinant to bring it into [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

- adding a scalar multiple of a row to another row will not change the value of the determinant, because the determinant is linear in its arguments (here: row vectors) and because it is alternating: two equal arguments will make it vanish (here: the addition)
- switching rows will flip the sign of the value of the determinant, because it is an alternating form

[Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) along colums then has only contributions at the diagonal positions.

This lowers the complexity for a $n\times n$ matrix from $O(n!)$ for the Leibniz formula or Laplace expansion to $O(n^3)$ for Gauss elimination.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose I have a square matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} $

now

$$A = LU $$

in general the determinant takes $ \mathcal{O}(n!)$

instead 
$$det(A) = det(LU) = det(L)det(U) $$
to calculate this

$$ det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} l_{ii} \prod_{i=1}^{n} u_{ii} $$

however if the numerical stability is in question you could use the QR decomp

$$ A = QR$$
$$ det(A) = det(QR) = det(Q)det(R) $$
the determinant of $Q$ is 1 as it is orthogonal

$$ det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} r_{ii}$$

now if the matrix is positive definite hermitian we can use the cholesky decomp

$$ A = R^{*}R$$
$$ det(A) = det(R^{*}R) = det(R^{*})det(R)$$
$$ det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} r_{ii}^{*} \prod_{i=1}^{n} r_{ii}$$

There is also an algorithm called the Bareiss algorithm which has $\mathcal{O}(n^{2})$ time complexity for Toeplitz matrices.