# Are there quicker and less error prone methods for finding determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Edit: I don't think this is a duplicate. That question is generally about efficient algorithms for calculating the determinant. While my question is about practical tips and tricks which can be used when doing this sort of thing by hand.

---

During one of the questions I was solving I came across the following determinant:

$\left|\matrix{t-1&3&0&-3\\2&t+6&0&-13\\0&3&t-1&-3\\1&4&0&t-8}\right|$

I solved it directly by expanding from the third column and got the result $(t-1)^4$.

However, along the way I made a couple of calculation errors and finding them took me a while. This got me thinking that maybe there are some tips and tricks I could use to calculate this in a faster less error prone method. Or maybe, at least know that I got the right answer in some way?

Any tips that could interest me?

Comment: Perhaps merge with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857224/efficient-algorithm-for-calculating-determinants/2857250#2857250

Comment: @Geronimo I don't think these questions are the same. That question is generally about efficient algorithms for calculating the determinant. While my question is about practical tips and tricks which can be used when doing this sort of thing by hand.

Comment: I see. I don't think it's a duplicate then.

Comment: The intent is obviously to develop by the third colon. For this matrix that is the way to go. You reduce at basically no effort to a smaller matrix. Then the question remains how to compute a det for 3 by 3 matrix efficiently, which likely could be asked separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the matrix in triangular form you can take the determinant by taking the product of the diagonal entries

Comment: Wonderful suggestion.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, I'll try it on my example and see if it works well for that one.